# Get file extension by mime type

Tags: go, mime-types

is there any GO library that convert mime type to file extension ?, I work on API that only give me mime type not the file format or even the file name

Comment: [`mime.ExtensionsByType`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#ExtensionsByType)

Comment: @mkopriva `mime.ExtensionsByType("video/mp4")` return nil :/

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22318#issuecomment-337591992

Comment: You can probably use https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#AddExtensionType to add more mime-type extensions. The mime types supported by default are here https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/mime/type.go#L59-L73 and agumented by https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/mime/type.go#L94-L102

Comment: sorry, i test `mime.ExtensionsByType("video/mp4")` in play.golang.org, and it's return empty slice - nil, but not in my local ubuntu,  thank you !

Comment: Probably because the playground doesn't have an "/etc/mime.types". In other words, if you don't control the machines your program is going to run in, don't expect the function to always work, or produce a particular result. Register the types you care about most explicitly.